# How to debug runtime crash (not segmentation fault) in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, debugging, gdb

I develop complex server program for Linux. It uses thousands of parallel SSL connections and implements custom protocol that serves client applications.
The problem is that this program sometimes crashes. It shows `Terminated` message in terminal and stops to work. I enabled automatic core dump to get crash report and analyze it with GDB. However, for any reason Linux (CentOS) doesn't create core dump. It looks like it creates core dump for segmentation fault only (I run `ulimit -c unlimited`, and when I provoke segmentation fault, dump is created).
Why Linux doesn't create core dump when software stops to work and shows `Terminated` message, and how to debug such issues if they exist in production enviroment only and never appear in test computer?

Comment: It shows *only* `Terminated`, or is there something other written too? Also it sounds like it might be an uncaught exception. Luckily a debugger will stop at both crashes like segmentation faults *and* crashes because of uncaught exceptions. So build a version with debug information, and run in the debugger.

Comment: Is running out of system memory a possibility?

Comment: It's also possible to get the "Terminated" message by receiving an uncaught `SIGTERM`.  Is your process using too much memory and being killed by the Out-Of-Memory killer?  The OOM killer can send `SIGTERM` instead of `SIGKILL` under some circumstances.

Comment: It shows only `Terminated`, nothing else; it really uses a lot of memory, however, the system has 64 G of memory, and it uses may be 8 G; can OOM kill program in such conditions? How to know what is limit when OOM kills program? @JoachimPileborg It may work, I'll try, the question is will GDB be able to debug software with so much parallel connections & memory usage.

Comment: Remember that your program is not alone on the machine, and it has to share memory with all other processes as well. So it may very well be the OOM killer that's kicking your process which means it will most likely not be possible to use a debugger.

Comment: The OOM killer logs the process name and ID. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html has more info, including how to configure it.